# Dynamic permissions in Asp.net Boilerplate

Tags: c#, aspnetboilerplate

I need to implement a dynamic permissions for [asp.net boilerplate](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/). However, the team there made sure to close all the doors to add a permission in the runtime.

Moreover, this peace of the implementation is not modular, and it is been initialized as a core dependency.

What is the best way to add permissions dynamically?

Comment: it's an open source framework so maybe there's a fork you could do?

Comment: This is in the very kernal. If I forked, I will not be able to use the Nuget libraries and their updated versions, or I should build everything again and push it to a local nuget store.

not an straightforward option

Comment: good point..silly idea really

Comment: maybe another bad idea - how does the next version of abp look in terms of doing this?  understand it's still in beta though

Comment: They are convinced that I don't want a dynamic permissions option and seems there is no plan to change this. I am waiting for their response.. let's see

Comment: i'd be curious in the use-case - not had the pleasure to need it myself

Comment: @Homam Can you describe your use case?

Comment: @aaron the application I am developing allows the user to create his own apps. I want ABP to populate those apps in the permissions and let the user configure permissions on them

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution to this issue  it took my a while until i managed to make this one.

i tried to override internal Permission Manager but it's hidden with no way to override that so the only way was to use "Windsor Handler Selectors" to force using of my PermissionManager

1) Go to [BoilerPlate](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate) and copy this files (PermissionDefinitionContextBase , PermissionDictionary,PermissionManager) to you project.

2) In Core Module in PreInitialize() add this Line at the start:

```
//Added this Handler so i can redirect every IPermissionManager to my Custom Implementation 

IocManager.IocContainer.Kernel.AddHandlerSelector(new PermissionManagerHandler());
```

3) Define PermissionManagerHandler

```
public class PermissionManagerHandler : IHandlerSelector
{
     public bool HasOpinionAbout(string key, Type service)
     {
        return typeof(IPermissionManager) == service;
     }
     public IHandler SelectHandler(string key, Type service, IHandler[] handlers)
     {
        return handlers.First(x => x.ComponentModel.Implementation == typeof(PermissionManager));
     }
}
```

4) in Core Module PostInitilize() Method add

```
    IocManager.Resolve<PermissionManager>().Initialize();
```

5) In Custom Permission Manager i Modified the Initialize Function by adding

```
Permissions.Clear();
```

6) every time i add a new Permission i call the initialize function so i can republish every thing using Command:

```
IocManager.Resolve<PermissionManager>().Initialize();
```

Comment: Hi @Ahmed, I have tried your solution but faced the error "No component for supporting the service Abp.Authorization.PermissionManager was found". Could you share some advices?

Comment: Where did this exception fire from ??

Comment: Hi @AhmedGhorab, I tried this method, but I keep getting the error 'Sequence contains no matching element' on line: 
return handlers.First(x => x.ComponentModel.Implementation == typeof(PermissionManager));
in the 'PermissionManagerHandler' file.
any idea what could I have done wrong?
thank you.